# Rails, contact page limiting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, contact-form

I'm creating a 'Contact' page in my rails application.

The user submits the form and an email will be sent to my email address. I want to limit the number of times this can be sent (say 1 per 15 minutes).

One solution is to log the ip address and time to a database table and check that before allowing the email to be sent. However, this means maintaining the table e.g. removing old records.

I was wondering if there is another suitable solution before going with the database table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is the best way out to do this. We need to track the machine IP if we want to limit and compare it everytime with its last request.